# Android - An algorithm to check recursively if a map is solvable

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am making an android [Hashikawekero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero)  puzzle game, I have implemented a algorithm to spawn nodes (Islands) at random positions using a 2-d array this works fine it creates the node at random position but most of the times the map cant be solved. The map nodes spawn at random.

BoardCreation.java Class - this generates the map.

```
package Island_and_Bridges.Hashi;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Random;

import static junit.framework.Assert.*;
//This class Creates the map by random using a 2d array

public class BoardCreation {
  // This class member is used for random initialization purposes.
  static private final Random random = new Random();

  // The difficulty levels.
  private static final int EASY = 0;
  static public final int MEDIUM = 1;
  static public final int HARD = 2;

  static public final int EMPTY = 0;

  private static int ConnectionFingerprint(BoardElement start, BoardElement end) {
    int x = start.row * 100 + start.col;
    int y = end.row * 100 + end.col;
    // Swap to get always the same fingerprint independent whether we are called
    // start-end or end-start
    if (x > y ) {
      int temp = x;
      x = y;
      y = temp;
    }
    Log.d("", String.format("%d %d" , x ,y));
    return x ^ y;
  }

  public class State {
    // The elements of the board are stored in this array.
    // A value defined by "EMPTY" means that its not set yet.
    public BoardElement [][] board_elements = null;

    public int [][] cell_occupied = null;

    // The width of the board. We only assume squared boards.
    public int board_width=0;


    public State(int width) {
      board_width = width;
      board_elements = new BoardElement[width][width];
      cell_occupied = new int[width][width];
    }

    public State CloneWithoutConnections() {
      State newstate = new State(board_width);
      if (board_elements != null) {
    newstate.board_elements = new BoardElement[board_elements.length][board_elements.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < board_elements.length; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < board_elements.length; ++j) {
        if (board_elements[i][j] == null)
              continue;
        newstate.board_elements[i][j] = board_elements[i][j].clone();
      }
    }
      }
      if (cell_occupied != null) {
          assert board_elements != null;
          newstate.cell_occupied = new int[board_elements.length][board_elements.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < board_elements.length; ++i) {
        System.arraycopy(cell_occupied[i], 0, newstate.cell_occupied[i], 0, board_elements.length);
    }
      }
      return newstate;
    }

    public void AddToBridgeCache(BoardElement first, BoardElement second) {
      if (first == null || second == null) { return; }
      final int fingerprint = ConnectionFingerprint(first, second);
      Log.d(getClass().getName(),
          String.format("Fingerprint of this bridge %d", fingerprint));
      // mark the end points as occupied.
      cell_occupied[first.row][first.col] = fingerprint;
      cell_occupied[second.row][second.col] = fingerprint;

      int dcol = second.col - first.col;
      int drow = second.row - first.row;

      if (first.row == second.row) {
    for (int i = (int) (first.col + Math.signum(dcol)); i != second.col; i += Math.signum(dcol)) {
      cell_occupied[first.row][i] = fingerprint;
        String.format("deleting bridge");
    }
      } else {
    assert first.col == second.col;
    for (int i = (int) (first.row + Math.signum(drow)); i != second.row; i+= Math.signum(drow)) {
      cell_occupied[i][first.col] = fingerprint;

    }
      }
    }
  } // end of state

  private State current_state, old_state;

  static private final int WIDTH_EASY = 7;

  private void NewGame(int hardness) {
    switch(hardness) {
      case EASY:
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Initializing new easy game");
    InitializeEasy();
    old_state = getCurrentState().CloneWithoutConnections();
    break;
    }
  }

  public void ResetGame() {
    if (old_state != null) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Setting board_elements to old_elements");
      setCurrentState(old_state.CloneWithoutConnections());
    } else {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "old_lements are zero");
    }
  }

  public BoardCreation(int hardness) {
    NewGame(hardness);
  }

  public boolean TryAddNewBridge(BoardElement start, BoardElement end, int count) {
    assertEquals(count, 1);
    assert (start != null);
    assert (end != null);
    final int fingerprint = ConnectionFingerprint(start, end);

    Log.d(getClass().getName(),
    String.format("considering (%d,%d) and (%d,%d)", start.row,start.col, end.row,end.col));
    if (start.row == end.row && start.col == end.col) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Same nodes selected!");
      return false;
    }
    assert count > 0;

    int dcol = end.col - start.col;
    int drow = end.row - start.row;

    // It must be a vertical or horizontal bridge:
    if (Math.abs(dcol) > 0 && Math.abs(drow) > 0) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "not a horizontal or vertical bridge.");
      return false;
    }

    // First we check whether start and end elements can take the specified bridge counts.
    int count_start = start.GetCurrentCount();
    int count_end = end.GetCurrentCount();

    if (count_start  + count > start.max_connecting_bridges ||
    count_end + count > end.max_connecting_bridges) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "This Bridge is not allowed");
      return false;
    }

    Log.d(getClass().getName(),
     String.format("Sums:%d @ (%d,%d)  and %d @ (%d,%d)",
       count_start, start.row, start.col,
       count_end, end.row, end.col));

    Connection start_connection = null;
    Connection end_connection = null;

    // Next we check whether we are crossing any lines.
    if (start.row == end.row) {
      for (int i = (int) (start.col + Math.signum(dcol)); i != end.col; i += Math.signum(dcol)) {
    if (getCurrentState().cell_occupied[start.row][i] > 0 &&
            getCurrentState().cell_occupied[start.row][i] != fingerprint) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Crossing an occupied cell.");
      return false;
    }
      }
      assert start.col != end.col;
      if (start.col > end.col) {
    start.connecting_east = GetOrCreateConnection(end, start.connecting_east);
    end.connecting_west = GetOrCreateConnection(start, end.connecting_west);
    start_connection = start.connecting_east;
    end_connection = end.connecting_west;
      } else {
    start.connecting_west = GetOrCreateConnection(end, start.connecting_west);
    end.connecting_east = GetOrCreateConnection(start, end.connecting_east);
    start_connection = start.connecting_west;
    end_connection = end.connecting_east;
      }
    } else {
      assert start.col == end.col;
      for (int i = (int) (start.row + Math.signum(drow)); i != end.row ; i += Math.signum(drow)) {
    if (getCurrentState().cell_occupied[i][start.col] > 0 &&
            getCurrentState().cell_occupied[i][start.col] != fingerprint) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Crossing an occupied cell.");
      return false;
    }
      }
      if (start.row > end.row ) {
    start.connecting_north = GetOrCreateConnection(end, start.connecting_north);
    end.connecting_south = GetOrCreateConnection(start, end.connecting_south);
    start_connection = start.connecting_north;
    end_connection = end.connecting_south;
      } else {
    start.connecting_south= GetOrCreateConnection(end, start.connecting_south);
    end.connecting_north = GetOrCreateConnection(start, end.connecting_north);
    start_connection = start.connecting_south;
    end_connection = end.connecting_north;
      }
    }
    start_connection.destination = end;
    end_connection.destination = start;
    start_connection.second += count;
    end_connection.second += count;

    getCurrentState().AddToBridgeCache(start, end);

    Log.d(getClass().getName(),
        String.format("New bridge added. Sums:%d @ (%d,%d)  and %d @ (%d,%d)",
         count_start, start.row,start.col,
         count_end, end.row,end.col));
    return true;
  }

  private Connection GetOrCreateConnection(
      BoardElement end,
      Connection connection) {
    if (connection!= null) { return connection; }
    return new Connection();
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
  private void InitializeEasy() {
      Random rand = new Random();

      String[][] debug_board_state = new String[7][7];
      setCurrentState(new State(WIDTH_EASY));
      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              debug_board_state[row][column] = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));

          }
      }

      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              System.out.print(debug_board_state[row][column] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
      for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
          for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {

                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.parseInt(debug_board_state[row][column]);
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

                  if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
                      getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }



  private void setCurrentState(State new_state) {
    this.current_state = new_state;
  }

  public State getCurrentState() {
    return current_state;
  }
}
```

What algorithm could I use to make sure the Map can be Solved (Islands Connected with Bridges) before spawning the nodes.

This is what the map looks like (don't mind the design)

[image]

Comment: The Wiki article says that it is a matter of procedural force, meaning that according to it, the only way to solve it to use a brute force approach. That being said, I did come across [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/hashiwokakero-build-bridges) question on another stack exchange site, which seems to do what you want, to a certain extent.

Comment: Considering specifics, you might be better off having pre-generated puzzles than generating new random ones and then brute forcing a solution. There are only a couple of hard constraints in there, from the programming perspective the rest would just be iteration. Alternatively, you could try starting with bridges rather than nodes.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov My goal is to achieve a random map every time the user starts the map meaning that the map will be different most of the time

Comment: @Jhon, that doesn't mean you can't randomly place a bunch of _bridges_ first, remove the invalid ones, then on each intersections place an island and discard of the bridges. So, bridges first, islands last. Just like the accepted answer suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider would be to start with a blank board. Place an island. Then place another island that can be connected to the first one (i.e. on one of the four cardinal directions). Connect the two with a bridge, and increment each island's count.

Now, pick one of the two islands and place another island that it can connect. Add the bridge and increment.

Continue in this way until you've placed the number of islands that you want to place.

The beauty here is that you start with an empty board, and during construction the board is always valid.

You'll have to ensure that you're not crossing bridges when you place new islands, but that's pretty easy to do, since you know where the existing bridges are.

Comment: this is the best way to generate map

Comment: Okay, I get it now, would it be most efficient to start at the position 0,0 and then add a island to position 0,1 connect bridges then add to postion 1,0 and do the same and so forth? or can i start at any position?

Comment: @Jhon If you start at 0,0, you have an artificial limit on the diversity of graphs you can create. There is no efficiency gain to start at 0,0. You're better off starting in a random position.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of how could I add this to me application? as i am not sure where to start code wise

Comment: @Jhon I don't have a code example. I suggest that you not start code-wise. Start with pencil and paper. Or, better, start with some scraps of cardboard and some sticks. Think about how you would go about building this by hand. Write down all the steps. Once you have the basic approach, *then* start writing code.